# tiny_mce textarea not working after call ajax load html content to a div

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, tinymce

I am using  tiny_mce in CodeIgniter. The normal html textarea is working successfully. But  when I am calling through an ajax function to display a html textarea content to my div, it is not showing tiny_mce controls. I Think it is the problem of re-initialization of javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it "re-initialization of javascript" but I think you get the basic problem. The call to `tinymce.init({selector: "textarea, .some-other-selector"})` works for all the elements of the page which are present at the time this call is executed. You've most likely placed it in a document.ready() block.

When you are adding a textarea through an AJAX call, you need to make this call again. The most suitable place to make this call would be in `.done()` callback of your ajax call. For example:

```
$.ajax(
    //your call parameters here
).done(function(data){
    //Assuming you want to insert the returned data into a div with class parent-div
    $("div.parent-div").html(data);
    tinymce.init({
        selector: ".parent-div textarea" //Assuming this is the element you want
    });
});
```